# Nested partition data structure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out what would be the best data structure/class for my use case.

I have several arrays (all of length `n`) that I want to use to create a partition. I want to be able to nest the partition at least one layer deep (hopefully will be clear from the example). I also want to be able to summarize the values of some other arrays (also of length `n`) with a `reduce`-like function, both within the inner (nested) and the outer (non-nested) partitions.

I'm thinking an API like this:

```
const arr1 = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1];
const arr2 = ["A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "B", "B", "A"];
const arr3 = [100, 250, 100, 300, 150, 250, 300, 150];

const partition = Partition.from(arr2)
  .nest(arr1)
  .reduceWith({arr3}, (a, b) => a + b, 0);

partition.outer() // { "A": { arr3: 600 }, "B": { arr3: 850 }, "C": { arr3: 150 } }
partition.inner() // { "A0": { arr3: 350 }, "A1" : { arr3: 250 }, "B0": { arr3: 550 }, "B1": { arr3: 300 }, "C1": { arr3: 150 } }
  

// ^^I used strings like "A0", "B1" etc..., as keys to make things a bit clearer,
// but in practice I might use JSON strings, e.g. "{"arr2":"B","arr1":0}", 
// to make the partition ids less ambiguous
```

Importantly, the specific values (but not the length or unique values) of the nesting arrays will change over time, so the data structure needs to allow for reactivity (I am using Solid JS). The inner partition might change more often than the outer one, and they should only be recomputed when necessary.

Anyone has any ideas/knows of a good pattern?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by modifications?

Comment: i dont know if i understand correct but you can use `reduce` to group and sum

Comment: You wrote *"specific values... will change"*: how will the API be informed about those? Or are you saying that a new call of `outer` or `inner` should just make sure to read the data from the arrays as they are at that very moment?

Comment: @trincot Ok, sorry for not being very clear, what I meant was that anytime the array changes, the `reduce` computations need to recompute. Technically, the values inside the array could stay the same, i.e. I could have a partitioning array `[0, 0, 1]` and send in a new batch of values `[0, 0, 1]` and that would still trigger the update. It's more that I can expect the values to be different, e.g. I could get `[1, 0, 1]`, and now I need to recompute the summaries since I essentially shuffled the first value from partition 0 to partition 1.

Comment: The update of the arrays should trigger recomputation, but that's fine, I can use Solid JS signals for that. I'm more concerned about the data structure to represent the partitioning.

Comment: But as far as I can see, it is the `inner()` and `outer()` calls that are the "triggers", or do you expect that the structures that are returned by those methods magically update without any contact with the API when the underlying values are mutated?

Comment: I don't know SolidJS, so I will leave this for someone else to look at. Better tag your question with it, since it seems your intended logic depends on it.

Comment: Actually, I was planning to have the `inner()` and `outer()` methods as derived signals (https://www.solidjs.com/tutorial/introduction_derived). So they should pass the update along. But you could think of them just as static values or getters, for the purpose of this q it doesn't really matter. The reactivity really shouldn't be a problem, I think.

Comment: My main concern is how to structure the class/object that organizes the partitions, since I kinda want two summaries of the same data: the coarser outer partition, and the finer inner partition.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a class `Partition` (which must be instanciated with `new`), and define a method `addLevel` (corresponding to both `from` and `nest` in your suggestion) which returns the instance again for chaining, and a method `reduceWith` which also returns the instance.

Then what you call `outer` and `inner` would be combined in a single method `produce` that takes a level as argument (like 1 for outer, and 2 for inner). This is more generic, and you could even generate a grand total (without partitioning) by passing level 0 as argument.

Here it is:

```js
class Partition {
    constructor() {
        this.levels = [];
        this.values = [];
    }
    addLevel(level) {
        this.levels.push(level);
        return this;
    }
    reduceWith(obj, reducer) {
        [this.key, this.values] = Object.entries(obj)[0];
        this.reducer = reducer;
        return this;
    }
    produce(level=1) {
        const levels = this.levels.slice(0, level);
        const {key} = this;
        return this.values.reduce((acc, value, i) => {
            const group = levels.map(level => level[i]).join("");
            if (group in acc) {
                acc[group][key] = this.reducer(acc[group][key], value);
            } else {
                acc[group] = {[key]: value};
            }
            return acc;
        }, {});
    }
}

const arr1 = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1];
const arr2 = ["A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "B", "B", "A"];
const arr3 = [100, 250, 100, 300, 150, 250, 300, 150];

const partition = new Partition()
  .addLevel(arr2)
  .addLevel(arr1)
  .reduceWith({arr3}, (a, b) => a + b);

console.log(partition.produce(0)); // { "": { arr3: 1600 } }
console.log(partition.produce(1)); // { "A": { arr3: 600 }, "B": { arr3: 850 }, "C": { arr3: 150 } }
console.log(partition.produce(2)); // { "A0": { arr3: 350 }, "A1" : { arr3: 250 }, "B0": { arr3: 550 }, "B1": { arr3: 300 }, "C1": { arr3: 150 } }
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it could work for me, I'm going to go try it out.